# No file after S3 boto put

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I am trying to write the file to S3 from the JSON structure in the Python 2.7 script. The code is as follows:

```
S3_bucket = s3.Bucket(__S3_BUCKET__)
result = S3_bucket.put_object(Key=__S3_BUCKET_PATH__ + 'file_prefix_' + str(int(time.time()))+'.json', Body = str(json.dumps(dict_list)).encode("utf-8"))
```

I end up with the S3 bucket handler is which is

```
s3.Bucket(name='bucket_name')
S3 file path is /file_prefix_1545039898.json
{'statusCode': s3.Object(bucket_name='bucket_name', key='/file_prefix_1545039898.json')}
```

But I see nothing on S3 - no files were created. I have a suspicion that I may require commit of some kind, bit all the manuals I came across are saying otherwise. Did anyone had a problem like this?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the leading slash works not as a standard path designator - it creates an empty name directory, which has not been seen. Removing the one puts things where they belong.